# php issue accessing array

Tags: php

I have the following code :

```
$results = $Q->get_posts($args);

foreach ($results as $r) {
    print $r['trackArtist'];
}
```

This is the output :

```
["SOUL MINORITY"]
["INLAND KNIGHTS"]
["DUKY","LOQUACE"]
```

My question is, if trackArtist is an array, why can't I run the implode function like this :

```
$artistString = implode(" , ", $r['trackArtist']);
```

Thanks

UPDATE :

Yes, it is a string indeed, but from the other side it leaves as an array so I assumed it arrives as an array here also.
There must be some processing done in the back.

Any idea how I can extract the information, for example from :
["DUKY","LOQUACE"]

to get :

DUKY, LOQUACE

Thanks for your time

Comment: This seems not to be an array but maybe an object?

Comment: Why do you think that `trackArtist` is array?

Comment: Try `var_dump($r['trackArtist']);` instead of `print();` to check if it is actually an array.

Comment: What makes you think trackArtist is an array?

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($results); echo "</pre>"; whats the Output ?

Comment: Your update is a different question, so technically you should accept one of the answers below and ask a new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a JSON string. You can do this to get the desired result:

```
$a = json_decode($r['trackArtist']); // turns your string into an array
$artistString = implode(', ', $a); // now you can use implode
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not actually an array; it's the string `'["DUKY","LOQUACE"]'` An array would be printed as `Array`. You can confirm this with:

```
var_dump($r['trackArtist']);
```

Answer (score 1):

To me content of `$r['trackArtist']` is NOT an array. Just regular string or object. Instead of `print` use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to figure this out and then adjust your code to work correctly with the type of object it really is.

Comment: I guess he meant `$r['trackArtist']` is an array, not 'trackArtist'.

Comment: yep. I refered to that. Edited